# PHP get image from URL to byte array and reverse

Tags: php, android

http://oep.esy.es/testimage.php
as you can see here, that is the output of png image. image is here:

http://oep.esy.es/images/object/1365-50.png

My code is that:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://oep.esy.es/images/object/1365-50.png");
echo $homepage;
```

I want to store as byte array because in Android client, I need that image so I need to pull it. Is it bad method?

But when I try to show image, it doesnot show:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, $homepage' />";
```

I also tried jpeg but did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `base64_encode()` function, something like:

```
$path = file_get_contents("http://oep.esy.es/images/object/1365-50.png");
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, " . base64_encode($path) ."'/>";
```